# PHP FastCGI SAPI: Reloading PHP Configuration

Tags: php, fastcgi, spawn-fcgi

I am using PHP FastCGI SAPI on my web hosting environment to run PHP applications. To spawn FCGI processes I use [spawn-fcgi](http://freshmeat.net/projects/spawn-fcgi) helper program. My problem is whenever I make a change to php.ini file, I have to kill and respawn each FastCGI server for the new configuration to take effect.

Is there a way to reload PHP configuration(ie. php.ini directives) without respawning each FastCGI server? I try sending hangup signal (ie. `kill -HUP PHPCGIPID`) to the servers but this will result in termination of the servers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, PHP's FastCGI interpreter doesn't react to signals like `HUP`, `USR1` or `USR2` to reload its configuration.

Maybe [PHP-FPM](http://php-fpm.org/) could help you to achieve what you want. On the downside, it requires patching PHP.

Comment: As of PHP 5.3.3, patching is no longer required.

Answer (score 1):

If the servers are spawned automatically, kill them. If they’re manually started, restart them. PHP doesn’t have the ability to reload its own configuration — and generally, killing/restarting is not a problem. Is there a reason why you can’t kill them in this instance?

Answer (score 1):

If you user PHP5 try this

```
sudo /etc/init.d/php5-fpm reload
```

Otherwise

```
sudo /etc/init.d/php-fpm reload
```

This command will restart server gracefully without closing existing connections.